# bitwise right shift affecting another short

Tags: c, linked-list, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I am using bitwise operators to shift the binary value of shorts within a linked list. The function is recursive and after an arbitrary number of occurrences, my right shift seems to affect the value of a short in the next link despite me not pointing to this link at all at this point of the function. Here is my code :

```
static void move_right(t_tetri *piece) {
  int i;
  i = 0;
  piece->x_offset++;
  while (i < piece->height) {
    piece->shape[i] = piece->shape[i] >> 1;
    i++;
  }
}

int ft_solve(t_map *map, t_tetri *list) {
  if (list == NULL) return (1);
  while (list->y_offset + list->height <= map->size) {
    while (list->x_offset + list->width <= map->size) {
      if (put_tetri(map, list)) {
        set_piece(map, list);
        if (ft_solve(map, list->next)) return (1);
        else unset_piece(map, list);
      }
      move_right(list);
    }
    reset_piece(list);
  }
  list->y_offset = 0;
  return (0);
}
```

`piece->shape` is an array containing 4 `short` but I'm mostly concerned about the first of these here. In certain cases (not all) when I go through the `move_right` function the value of `piece->next->shape[0]` is shifted in the same way, which poses a big problem for the next recursion of ft_solve.

Would anyone have any idea?

I can post more of my code if necessary, I'm not really used to ask questions here so if you need more information I'm ready to add it.

Comment: My guess is you have an uninitialized `list->next`. So the problem is in your code that builds the list, not the code you've posted here.

Comment: Run your program under a debugger, and check all your `next` pointers when this happens.

Comment: You're probably accessing out of bounds of an array

Comment: Step 1: Change type: `short shape` --> `unsigned short shape`

Comment: In `while (i < piece->height)` , I'd expect the bit shifted out to be used in the next element.